# Unidirectional @OnetoMany mapping deletes all relationships and re-adds remaining ones rather than removing the specific one

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, hibernate-mapping

Given the following code

```java
public class Course {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Review> reviews = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class Review {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String rating;
    private String description;
}
```

Saved course with 2 reviews.

If I try to remove one review from course.

```java
course.getReviews().remove(0);
```

Hibernate fires following queries.

```sql
delete from course_reviews where course_id=? 
binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [1]
insert into course_reviews (course_id, reviews_id) values (?, ?) 
binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [1]
binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - [3]
```

Notice that it deletes all the relationships first and then inserts the remaining. Why this behavior? Why couldn't it be more specific and delete just that one record storing the relationship.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this is due to bag semantics(because you use a `List` rather than `Set` for reviews) or just because Hibernate sometimes does so called "collection recreations". Try using a `Set`.

Comment: Thanks! this worked. But why does it show such different behavior for Set and List even though the action is quite the same. Can you point me to some article where I can read about this collection recreations

Comment: The problem is that when you have bag semantics i.e. "multiple possible rows with the same values", you can't just execute delete statement to delete "the first" element. So Hibernate has to remove all elements and then reinsert them.

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate does that because it has no idea about how the entities are related. Since there is no information about how relations are identified, it uses the only information it has - objects in the memory. So it clears the table by the predicate and persists the entities from memory.

You need to use `@JoinColumn` on the child side and `mappedBy` parameter of `@OneToMany` on the parent side.

Comment: But the objects do contain the information. Both Course, and the Review that was deleted, have ids populate in itd. The reviews_id required to be more specific in the delete query "delete from course_reviews where course_id=?" is already known to hibernate at the time of deletion, cant understand why hibernate cant figure that out.

Comment: @KP- there is no information whatsoever. You need to understand how hibernate mapping works. Take a look at this article: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But if I just change it to Set instead of List, it fires a more specific query "delete from course_reviews where course_id=? and reviews_id=?"

Comment: @KP- no problem. Sure, that's an easy workaround. You'll suffer performance issues soon though;)

Comment: This way of mapping definitely is not the right way to map One-to-Many and I agree with your comments. But the question I had was more specifically about the deleting and re-adding of relationships:)

Answer (score 2):

First of all the behavior that you see is described in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many):

> The unidirectional associations are not very efficient when it comes to removing child entities. In the example above, upon flushing the persistence context, Hibernate deletes all database rows from the link table (e.g. Person_Phone) that are associated with the parent Person entity and reinserts the ones that are still found in the `@OneToMany` collection.
>
> On the other hand, a bidirectional `@OneToMany` association is much more efficient because the child entity controls the association.

As for the question:

> Why this behavior? Why couldn't it be more specific and delete just that one record storing the relationship.

The answer is not so simple and require deep diving into the hibernate source code.

The key point of the entity's collection processing in hibernate is the [PersistentCollection](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/collection/spi/PersistentCollection.java) interface. As it stated in the comments to this interface:

> Hibernate *wraps* a java collection in an instance of `PersistentCollection`. This mechanism is designed to support tracking of changes to the collection's persistent state and lazy instantiation of collection elements. The downside is that only certain abstract collection types are supported and any extra semantics are lost.

The important place in our discussion have the following method of this interface:

```java
/**
  * Do we need to completely recreate this collection when it changes?
  *
  * @param persister The collection persister
  * @return {@code true} if a change requires a recreate.
  */
boolean needsRecreate(CollectionPersister persister);
```

Hibernate creates an action queue for scheduling creates/removes/updates at flushing time (see the [AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushCollections](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/event/internal/AbstractFlushingEventListener.java#L247) method). So, our collection belongs to one of the [CollectionUpdateAction](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/action/internal/CollectionUpdateAction.java) action in this queue.

As you can see from the `CollectionUpdateAction.execute()` method implementation, hibernate checks need of a collection recreation based on the on the `collection.needsRecreate(persister)` call.

The `PersistentCollection` interface has the following hierarchy of implementations:

```
PersistentCollection
   |
   |-- AbstractPersistentCollection
           |
           |-- PersistentArrayHolder
           |-- PersistentBag
           |-- PersistentIdentifierBag
           |-- PersistentList
           |-- PersistentMap
                  |
                  |-- PersistentSortedMap
           |
           |-- PersistentSet
                  |
                  |-- PersistentSortedSet
```

Actually, the `needsRecreate` method implemented only in the `AbstractPersistentCollection` and overridden for the `PersistentBag` in the following way:

```java
@Override
public boolean needsRecreate(CollectionPersister persister) {
    return !persister.isOneToMany();
}
```

Hibernate decides to what type from the above hierarchy a collection belongs at time of parsing your domain model.

1. When you use the described in your question mapping:

```java
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Review> reviews;
```

hibernate will treat it as `PersistentBag` and the method `PersistentCollection.needsRecreate` returns `true` (because the [BasicCollectionPersister](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/persister/collection/BasicCollectionPersister.java) is used).

2. You can use the `@OrderColumn` [annotation](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/OrderColumn.html):

```java
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@OrderColumn
private List<Review> reviews;
```

in this case the collection will be treated as the `PersistentList` and you will avoid the collection recreation. But this is also required additional *order column* (must be of integral type) in the `Course_Review` table. And when you will try to remove an item from the beginning of the list you will have also a lot of the order columns updates.

3. You can use the `Set` interface instead of `List` (as was noticed by *Christian Beikov*):

```java
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<Review> reviews;
```

in this case the collection will be treated as the `PersistentSet` and you will avoid the collection recreation as well. When using Sets, it’s [very important](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#collections-set) to supply proper `equals/hashCode` implementations for child entities. A [better](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-model-pojo-equalshashcode) `equals/hashCode` implementation, making use of a natural-id or business-key. And you will be able to remove an item from this collection only by the object reference as the method `remove(int index)` just absent in the `Set` interface.