# Spring Jpa - Records deleted and re-inserted upon addition/deletion in join table

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have 3 entities user, role and user_roles.

`User` and `Role` entity have a one-to-many relationship with the `UserRoles` entity which is a join table. I have added `user_roles` as a entity because we plan to have additional properties in future as part of the join table.

**User Entity**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = RandomIdGenerator.GENERATOR_NAME)
    @GenericGenerator(name = RandomIdGenerator.GENERATOR_NAME, strategy = "com.cs.util.RandomIdGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
    private String lastName;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<UserRole> userRoles = new ArrayList<UserRole> ();

    @JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class)
    public Long getId ()
    {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId (Long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail()
    {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail (String email)
    {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName)
    {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Transient
    public Set<Role> getRoles()
    {
        Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role> ();
        for (UserRole userRole : this.userRoles)
        {
            roles.add (userRole.getRole ());
        }
        return roles;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public List<UserRole> getUserRoles()
    {
        return userRoles;
    }
}
```

**Role Entity**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="roles")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "role_id")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = RandomIdGenerator.GENERATOR_NAME)
    @GenericGenerator(name = RandomIdGenerator.GENERATOR_NAME, strategy = "com.cs.util.RandomIdGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="name", nullable = false)
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name="description", nullable = true)
    private String description;
    
    @Column(name = "suspend_flag")
    private int suspendFlag;

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "roles_permission",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "permission_id"))
    private Set<Permission> permissions= new HashSet<>();
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "role")
    private List<UserRole> userRoles = new ArrayList<UserRole>();

    @JsonSerialize(using=ToStringSerializer.class)
    public Long getId ()
    {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId (Long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName ()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName (String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription ()
    {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription (String description)
    {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Set<Permission> getPermissions ()
    {
        return permissions;
    }

    public int getSuspendFlag ()
    {
        return suspendFlag;
    }
    public void setSuspendFlag (int suspendFlag)
    {
        this.suspendFlag = suspendFlag;
    }
}
```

**UserRole Entity**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_roles")
public class UserRole
{
    public UserRole ()
    {
    }
    
    public UserRole (User user, Role role)
    {
        this.user = user;
        this.role = role;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_role_id")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = RandomIdGenerator.GENERATOR_NAME)
    @GenericGenerator(name = RandomIdGenerator.GENERATOR_NAME, strategy = "com.cs.util.RandomIdGenerator")
    private Long      id;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "role_id")
    private Role role;

    public Long getId ()
    {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId (Long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    @JsonIgnore
    public User getUser ()
    {
        return user;
    }
    public void setUser (User user)
    {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Role getRole ()
    {
        return role;
    }
    public void setRole (Role role)
    {
        this.role = role;
    }
}
```

With above code everything works fine but whenever I insert or delete a `user_role` all the records in the `user_role` table are deleted and re-inserted again.

For instance when I associate a new user_role to a user the existing user_role is deleted first and then it is re-associated again along with the new user role.

```
Hibernate: delete from user_roles where user_role_id=?
Hibernate: insert into user_roles (role_id, user_id, user_role_id) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into user_roles (role_id, user_id, user_role_id) values (?, ?, ?)
```

This is how I add a user role to the user entity.

```java
UserRole userRole = new UserRole(user,role);
user.getUserRoles ().add (userRole);
m_userRepository.save (_user)
```

And then delete the user role from user like below

```java
List<UserRole> uRolesTobeRemoved = new ArrayList<UserRole> ();
for(Role role : userRoles)
{
    UserRole uRole = user.getUserRoles ().stream ().filter (userRole -> 
    userRole.getRole ().getId () == role.getId ()).collect (Collectors.toList ()).get (0);
    uRolesTobeRemoved.add (uRole);
}
user.getUserRoles ().removeAll (uRolesTobeRemoved);
```

I'm not sure what is missing.

Comment: `whenever I insert or delete a user_role` - Could you please show how exactly you delete or insert a `user_role`.

Comment: @SternK i have updated my question to include the insertion and deletion logic at the end.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you see this behaviour due to so called "collection recreation".
Try to replace `List<UserRole> userRoles` to `Set<UserRole> userRoles`.
More detailed explanation you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64363313/unidirectional-onetomany-mapping-deletes-all-relationships-and-re-adds-remainin/64405508#64405508).